# Django models and views

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create my first project. Like Stack Overflow questions and answers on specific theme. I create my own user by AbstractBaseUser. And now I want to create Question and Answer model.

My model:

```
class Question(models.Model):

text = models.TextField()
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)
def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

class Answer(models.Model):

```
text = models.TextField()
date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)
question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
```

class Tags(models.Model):

```
TYPE_OF_TAGS = (
    ('First tag', 'First'),
    ('Second tag', 'Second'),
    ('Third tag', 'Third'),
    )
type_of_tag = models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=TYPE_OF_TAGS, blank=True)
question = models.ManyToManyField(Question)
```

my views:

```
def question(request):

args = {}
args.update(csrf(request))
args['form'] = QuestionForm()
args['profile'] = CustomUser.objects.filter(pk = request.user.pk)
args['author'] = Question()

if request.POST:
    args['form'] = QuestionForm(request.POST)
    obj = args['form'].save(commit=False)
    obj.save()
    args['author'].author = args['profile']
    args['author'].save()
    return redirect(reverse(question))

return render(request, 'questions.html', args)
```

I create first view for answer, and I have error when I send form:

> null value in column "author_id" violates not-null constraint

I think I'm going in the wrong direction. And I have bad models and bad views. Why I have this error and what wrong with my models?

Comment: You need create the Author and associate to the form Question before create the Question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your business rules don't allow to have null author on a question, you must set the author value to your obj before saving it.
Something like:

```
def question(request):

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = QuestionForm()
    args['profile'] = CustomUser.objects.filter(pk = request.user.pk)

    if request.POST:
        args['form'] = QuestionForm(request.POST)
        obj = args['form'].save(commit=False)
        obj.author = args['profile']
        obj.save()
        return redirect('your_redirect_url')

    return render(request, 'questions.html', args)
```

You have another option: 
You can pass to the QuestionForm an initial dictionary of:

```
{
    'author' : CustomUser.objects.filter(pk = request.user.pk)
}
```

Something like:

```
def question(request):

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = QuestionForm(initial={
        'author': CustomUser.objects.filter(pk = request.user.pk)    
    })

    if request.POST:
        args['form'] = QuestionForm(request.POST)
        obj = args['form'].save()
        return redirect('your_redirect_url')

    return render(request, 'questions.html', args)
```

NOTE: It's important to render in your questions.html template, a hidden field for the author value, so it is included in the POST data.

Comment: thanks to people like you. I can teach the Django development! <3 Its worked. Plz tell me my model logik is good for these solutions, like question - answer. I'm not sure of the correctness model - tags. Thank a lot!

Comment: I think you model is right. The only thing I'd do differently is to put the ManyToMany field in the Question model, instead of Tag (I think it's better to name models in singular). The meaning is exactly the same, but it's more natural to say "A question has tags" than say "A tag has questions". Besides, if you make the Tag model independent of the Question model, you may also put a ManyToMany field to Tag in the Answer model, allowing to 'tag' answers too.

Comment: awesome! Thank you very much for this detailed answer

Comment: One more question plz. Tags fill better create in model like CharField and choices or personal charfield for one tag ?

Comment: I think the most useful way is to let the user type a list of strings (maybe comma separated). In the form, make a clean_tags (asuming your form field is named 'tags') that process that big string, splitting it into candidate tags. For each one, find out if a tag with the same content already exist (if so, use it) and create new tags for non existing strings.

Comment: If you also add a type-ahead function that query the DB looking for matching tags, at the same time a user is typing, and allowing him to pick one of the results, it is more easy to use, and also avoid people to create new tags that are equivalent to already existing tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use `null = True` for Foreign key fields, that can be null.

```
class Question(models.Model):

    #...
    author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, null = True, blank = True)
```

Otherwise, specify the value of author when saving the model in first place, which you are doing erroneously. I'm unable to understand what does `args['author'] = Question()` means? You should do something on the lines of

```
args['author'] = CustomUser() # in your question view
```

instead.

Comment: Thank you. i change my model and this line in view     `args['profile'] = CustomUser.objects.get(pk = request.user.pk)`  And when i send form, field  Question.author is None

Comment: Change the model, is not the correct solution, because i think the Question, must have a author.

Comment: Then specify the author as I mentioned that too in "otherwise" section